# Erro no visual studio runtimelibrary error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiladores

Esta apresentando o seguinte erro de runtimelibrary error:

> Error LNK2038 mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value
>   'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in
>   Aimbot.obj    INDIGO  C:\smef-s-Indigo-Remasterd-master\INDIGO\libprotobuf.lib(message_lite.obj)  1

Eu estou com 40 errors desse mesmo tipo .

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta não foi muito clara, onde e quando que esse erro aparece ? Mas geralmente esse tipo de defeito é resolvido com uma Reinstalação.
Tente desinstalar o programa, apagar todas as pastas sobrarem (Que restarem da desinstalação) e instalar o Aplicativo novamente, se o erro persistir, entre em contado com o suporte da Microsoft.